# Accessing Local interface (EJB3) within 2 different application on same JBOSS instance (same JVM)

Tags: jboss7.x, jndi, ejb-3.1

Can I access Local interface from another application within same JBOSS instance?
Example:
In my shared library:

```
@Local
class EmployeeLocal {
    void doAction();}
@Remote 
class EmployeeRemote{
    void doAction();
}

EAR Application:
@Stateless
class EmployeeService implements EmployeRemote,EmployeeLocal {
    @Override
    public doAction() { System.out.println(“Do something!”)};
    }
}


WAR Application:
public AccessEJB {
    @EJB
    IEmployeeLocal employeLocal;
```

//Injection doesn't work either, throws exception saying not EJB  "Caused //by:org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: //JBAS014544: No EJB found with interface of type 'IEmployeeLocal' for binding

```
    public void doSomethingWithEJB() {
            IEmployeeRemote iEmployee =
                (IEmployeeRemote ) context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/EmployeeService!EmployeRemote");
                iEmployee.doAction(); //THIS WORKS
                            IEmployeeLocal iEmployeeLocal =
                (IEmployeeLocal) context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/EmployeeService!EmployeLocal");
                iEmployee.doAction(); //THIS DOESN'T WORK   
}
```

}

If this is possible, then please provide a example (with jboss configuration required).  I have tried dependency injection, all sorts of jndi lookups

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/communication-between-ejb-modules-in-the-same-application-server/) will help you a bit?

Comment: Thank you! This clears up a lot.  @Piotr, I'm assuming nothing has changed in Java 8.

Comment: I doubt that Java 8 changed anything. It's more like how the application server is implemented and what Java EE specification it respects. I believe I tested it for EE 6 but I don't recall any changes in the specification for EE 7.